# Gradle: calling assemble for one flavor to trigger multiple

Tags: android, gradle

My current situation is that in my build.gradle I've got 4 flavors

```
   productFlavors {
        internal {
        }

        internal1 {
        }

        internal2 {
        }

        internal3 {
        }
   }
```

I'd like that when I call:
./gradlew assemble internalRelease

the gradle should build all the "internalX" flavors internal1, internal2 and internal3.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: can you able to give a better explanation about internalX and you problem ?

Comment: bascically all I need to achieve is to build all the internalX flavors after calling just: 
./gradlew assembleInternalRelease